# How to test, using test data, a Process Builder that fires a Flow which posts to Collaboration Group's Chatter feed?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, process-builder, chatter, collaborationgroup

I am testing a Process Builder process which (1) looks at a new Support_Ticket__C, (2) auto-updates some picklist fields based on what the user entered on creation, then (3) fires a Flow which (4) posts a Chatter to a Collaboration Group. I have created test data to create the initial support tickets, but now I can't create Collaboration Groups without receiving the error on insert that they already exist. How can I test that the Flow fired and created a Chatter post if, in my test setup, I can't create the Collaboration Group? Is there something I can do in my test setup or within the individual tests themselves to see that a FeedItem was created for the specific groups after insert?